# Android: Contact list not sort by name

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch my phone contacts in alphabetical sort order.Its fetch name by fast but not getting sort order .I tried **ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC"** also **ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"** but not getting good result.

My code is

```
 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       Log.e("Tag ","Name " + name);

    }
    phones.close();
```

is there any solution for fetching the contacts in sorted order

Can any one please help me
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
       ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1", 
       null, 
       "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Comment: This works great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this and it will work. Its the fast and best way. You have to use this because there may b cases with alphabets , digits , special chars and null.

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt of one of my app:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = String.format("%s = '%s'", ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    // Make this order case insensitive.
    String orderBy = "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + ") ASC";

    contactCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, orderBy);
```

So basically, try `DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY` instead of just `DISPLAY_NAME`. Beware of case sensitiveness of the orderBy clause as well.

Comment: Thank u now it is sorting but the contact name is repeating by two times

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to get all contacts sorted alphabetically

```
public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC"); //cursor fetches data alphabetically
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        ContactDetail cntactDetails = new ContactDetail();
        cntactDetails.setName(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        cntactDetails.setNumber(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

        String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
        cntactDetails.setId(id);
        phones.close();
}
```

**NOTE** - here `ContactDetail` is a model class for storing contacts.